# Orbeon Forms pruning empty xml elements

Tags: orbeon

How can I prune an empty element of data.xml which generated using work-flow send button? For instance we may prune invisible controls/section making value = "false" in properties-local.xml file `<property
    as="xs:boolean"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.prune.*.*"
    value="false"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oxf.fr.detail.send.success.prune.*.*` property allows you to control whether non-relevant  elements are pruned, not empty elements. There is no property to remove empty elements, but this is something you can do on the receiving side, say, with XSLT. And a couple of precisions:

- By *prune*, we mean *remove from the XML*.
- *Non-relevant* elements (a terminology that comes from XForms) are the elements for which the visibility rule you defined in Form Builder returns `false`.